# Bayesian Neural Network Inference

Tags: statistics, probability, mathematics, bayesian

In a paper about Bayesian Neural Network, I saw the following algorithm:

Algorithm 1 Inference procedure for a BNN.

Define $p(\theta\mid D)$;

for $i = 0$ to $N$ do

- Draw $θ_i \sim p(\theta\mid D)$;
- $y_i = \Phi\theta_i(x)$;

end for

return $Y = \{y_i\mid i \in [0, N)\}, \Theta = \{\theta_i\mid i \in [0, N)\}$;

The paper then states :

In Algorithm 1, $Y$ is a set of samples from $p(y\mid x, D)$ and
$\Theta$ a collection of samples from $p(\theta\mid D)$. Usually, aggregates
are computed on those samples to summarize the uncertainty
of the BNN and obtain an estimator for the output $y$. This
estimator is denoted by $\hat y$.

But I dont understand why it states that $Y$ is a set of samples from $p(y\mid x, D)$. Shouldn't it be a sample from $p(y/x,0)$? If someone could give me a math proof or the intuition.

Comment: I think you should add a reference to the paper you're talking about.

Comment: Here is the paper : https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.06823.pdf

Comment: The algorithm is at page 3